# Authentication Service throws Procedure invocation error post upgrade from MFP 6.3 to MFP 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

[image]Authentication adapter throwing "Procedure invocation error" sometimes. Tried clearing cache and cookies but still the same. So we tried to login from different system for same user and it works. This is quite confusing as once we try with different ID in browser where issue occurred, it works and then it works with Member ID which has issue as well. Auth required is not coming in response when issue occurs.

we have tried to look into logs and found WorklightAuthenticationException from Authentication Adapter while trying security test procedure.

Authentication Adapter code:
var result = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    WL.Logger.info("Authentication service : " + JSON.stringify(result));

```
authResponse = prepareJSONResponse(result,channelId);
WL.Logger.info('Formatted response -> ' + JSON.stringify(authResponse));    

if(result.isSuccessful == false){
    WL.Logger.info("Error: " + result.errorMessage);
    return onAuthRequired(null, "Error in connecting to server. Please try again later.");
}


if(typeof authResponse.errorMessage != 'undefined'){
    WL.Logger.info("Error is defined" +authResponse.errorMessage);
    return onAuthRequired(null, authResponse);
}


WL.Logger.info("Authentication service success: " + JSON.stringify(result));
WL.Logger.info("userIdentity Parameters: " + inputParams.CorpId);
var userIdentity = {
        userId: inputParams.CorpId,
        displayName: inputParams.CorpId,
       attributes: {
            foo: "bar"
        }
};
WL.Logger.info("userIdentity::"+JSON.stringify(userIdentity));
WL.Server.setActiveUser("SingleStepAuthRealm", userIdentity);


return {
        authRequired: false
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening due to the requests going from one node to another node. Handled it in Load balancer to send requests to specific node based on cookies and post that it works fine.

Comment: Was a 6.3 war file deployed on 7.1? And was the runtime set to work in session independent mode?

Comment: Its 7.1 WAR deployed on 7.1 but after upgrading it in two nodes, the application works independently in each node but when we enable both the nodes then it doesn't allow to login. we haven't set any session independent mode explicitly so i guess it will be default.

Comment: Also Vivin, can you please tell me if we need to set this to session dependent or independent mode considering we have two nodes and both doesn't have any interaction. Only Load balancer routes the requests to each node.

Comment: By default it is session independent. But if the war file had any entries for session dependent, then that value takes effect. Also, what is the application server? Liberty or WAS?

Comment: Also, note that if you are using browser based environments , it has to be session dependent.

Comment: we have two applications one with desktopbrowser and other has android, iphone, mobilewebapp envionments. we are using liberty server.

Answer (score 0):

The description mentions about clearing cache and cookies and using browser.

Browser based environments are not supported in session independent mode. These work only in session dependent mode. As such, it is imperative that session based affinity be enabled to ensure the requests land in the same JVM for authentication state to be preserved.

More details can be found here : [Session-independent mode](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_session_indep.html)

Comment: Vivin - One more query, is there a way to see if the WAR deployed in production is session dependent or independent. We have migrated from 6.3 to 7.1 last week and didn't go any setting specific to session dependency. So just want to confirm what mode it is working on currently.

Comment: Logs will print it.